Error Plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings'] was not found in any of the following sources:, when upgrading to "react-native": "0.75.1"
Trying to upgrade react native 0.75.1, using https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper.
running into error
Settings file 'mobile/android/settings.gradle' line: 2

 * What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings'] was not found in any of the following sources:

 * Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
 * Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
 * Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

here is file android>settings.gradle
pluginManagement { includeBuild("../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin") }
plugins { id("com.facebook.react.settings") }
extensions.configure(com.facebook.react.ReactSettingsExtension){ ex -> ex.autolinkLibrariesFromCommand() }
rootProject.name = 'mobileAppName'
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')

which is what is required from the react-native upgrade helper.
tried commenting out the line and adding the plugin in android/app/build.gradle
like so
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.settings"
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
apply plugin: "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"

but the next line errors out
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'com' for settings 'android' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.
from line
extensions.configure(com.facebook.react.ReactSettingsExtension){ ex -> ex.autolinkLibrariesFromCommand() }

so the plugin has to be imported in settings.gradle
does anyone have a solution or workaround to get the plugin "com.facebook.react.settings") working??

check your @react-native/gradle-plugin resolution in yarn.lock/package-lock.json; if you have any lingering other than 0.75.1 (eg i have 0.74.1 left in there) you have to remove node_modules and regenerate your lock file
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/46046#issuecomment-2291641341

...and don't forget to delete your node_modules dir.

I encountered the same error on Windows.
When I opened my project in Android Studio, it shown a warning:
Multiple Gradle daemons might be spawned because
the Gradle JDK and JAVA_HOME locations are different.

This resolved the issue for me:

Set JAVA_HOME environment variable to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
Restart VSCode


./gradlew --stop helped me stop running daemons and everything is ok now. Thanks !

I had the same issue
this is my android>settings.gradle file


pluginManagement { includeBuild("../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin") }
plugins { id("com.facebook.react.settings") }
extensions.configure(com.facebook.react.ReactSettingsExtension){ ex -> ex.autolinkLibrariesFromCommand() }
rootProject.name = 'InAppPurchase'
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')



I updated the @react-native/gradle-plugin to latest version but it did not solve the issue.
when I run npm run android instead of npm start this worked in my case.

Just Remove .settings from the android>settings.gradle
Before Change
Plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings']

After change
Plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react']

Then verify your android>build.gradle file contians the dependencies:
dependencies {
    classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
}


Downgrade the distributionUrl in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and rebuild your project.
From gradle-8.8-all.zip to gradle-8.5-all.zip or compatibility version
Or you can try the trick: https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/1328#issuecomment-2302466257

I was also getting the same error got the fix
after installing node_modules / setup of react native project close your terminal and in new terminal run below command this works for me
npm run android --clear-cache

I have faced same issue on react native version 0.75.2.
Solved the issue by

installing @react-native/gradle-plugin@0.75.2
opening project in android studio
clean project and run

for reference check this link

If you have problem and you use windows. exec this cmd :
".\android\gradlew.bat build --refresh-dependencies"

The only method which worked for me! Thank you!

I had to run npx react-native doctor and chose 'fix' for it to work. brand new set up RN 0.76.0 on windows

Run:
npm install @react-native/gradle-plugin@0.75.1 --exact

or if using yarn
yarn add @react-native/gradle-plugin@0.75.1 --exact


I had the same issue. And I solved it! Just uninstall the Java extensions in VSCode, reload VSCode, and that's it! You might need to do a clean install, but this worked for me. I didn't have any issues doing a clean install without the Java extensions.

I fixed this issue by updating node js version.
run following command to update:
choco install nodejs --version="22.9.0" // run this in command prompt as administrator


This here: "../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin", could be the culprit.
Check package-lock.json for the actual address to your gradle-plugin. It could be: "node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin". Could

This is my solution
I got this related error after upgrading from RN 0.74.1 to RN 0.75.4.:
Settings file '[PATH]/android/settings.gradle' line: 3 * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'com' for settings 'android' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.

After searching for hours I found the solution.
If you have the react-native-windows dependency in your package.json ensure it has the same version as the react-native dependency. Fix this first before performing the next steps.
If this does not fix it after performing the steps below, it has something to do with another outdated dependency in the packages.json
Perform the next steps from the root of your project.

Empty your yarn.lock file. (Deleting the file will make yarn unhappy)
Delete node_modules folder
Run: yarn install
Run: cd android
Run: gradlew clean
Run: yarn android

This will fix it. Happy coding! 

Update android/build.gradle file as shown its for latest RN
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "35.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 35
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        playServicesLocationVersion = "21.0.1"
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.24"
        // RNNKotlinVersion = kotlinVersion
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
        // classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
   google()
   mavenLocal()
   mavenCentral()
    maven {
      // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
      url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
   maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
}


apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Issue Trace
* What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings']

BUILD FAILED in 22s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

This build issue occurs because of the misconfiguration of gradle files. to resolve, i have clean the gradele file and reassembled it. following commands fill helps to resolve the issue.
* remove the directory : PROJECT/android/.gradle
* run following commands one by one
  cd android
./gradlew --stop
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleDebug

when gradle assemble is done, we can run the application via metro bundler using any of the following command
npm start or npm run android

Delete android=>.gradle folder then open terminal at  android folder and run
./gradlew clean
and then
npx react-native run-android

I just deleted .gradle folder from android folder and run "npm run android" again and it worked.
